# Flutter Media Card - Picture and Title with link

Tags: image, flutter

How do I put a `image.network()` inside a card?

```
new Card(
         child: new Container(
        Image.network(data[index]['image'], width:200.0, height: 200.0,fit: BoxFit.cover),
          child: new Text(data[index]['title']),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        ),
       )
```

It works fine if I remove the `Image.network(...)` line.

```
new Card(
            child: new Container(
              child: new Text(data[index]['title']),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
             ),
       )
```

I solved it myself but will put the code here just in case anyone else has this issue. As there is no documentation on how to do what I wanted to do. I am sure there maybe better ways to get the outcome like (text over the bottom of the image, but this question was how to get an image from network to show in a card)

```
 new Card(
                        child: new Container(
                          child: new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.network(data[index]['image'], fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                                    Text(data[index]['title'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  ]
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                    )
```

Comment: Can you tel me what is the expected result?

Comment: You should post your answer below, as an answer, and not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself but will put the code here just in case anyone else has this issue. As there is no documentation on how to do what I wanted to do. I am sure there maybe better ways to get the outcome like (text over the bottom of the image, but this question was how to get an image from network to show in a card)

```
 new Card(
                        child: new Container(
                          child: new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Image.network(data[index]['image'], fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                                    Text(data[index]['title'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  ]
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                    )
```